# Is adding more proof/evidence not allowed?

Tags: discussion

So there's a question someone already answered, but I found that the answer can be improved by adding a few more examples. But it seems like this is not allowed...

As you can see below this image, I don't think that there is an error about this edit, it was more likely to make the answer better...

Shouldn't we do that? Keep improving the answers?

[image]

The rejection reason is:

> **"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."**

But I did not have that intention, I was just trying to make the answer more perfect... that's it...

So is it not recommended to do edits like these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was one of the people who rejected the edit and i mostly read the title of the response in the Suggested Edit Moderation Queue which was *"clearly conflicts with author's intent"*

this is just me but personally i feel that unless the answer is a Community Wiki edits to answers should be limited to formatting, grammar/spelling correction and/or clarification  and the only time time i feel to add new stuff to an answer is when you're quoting relevant parts from exiting links or posting something supportive to the existing information presented in the answer (ie. [adding a manga page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52341) or [episode screenshots](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52324)).

now it does look like you were coming from a good place and it's not like the information was wrong, i just felt that it wasn't right as an edit. now i could be wrong and others who rejected it might have had different reasons but if the rejected edit was incorrect and Ero Sɘnnin did want the information in the answer [they can override the rejection being the post owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028).

Comment: Ok, I understand that, I will be more careful on editing those answer and question.